# What exactly happens while you assign a reference to an element in Array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am doing the following statements in Java,

```
Obj t[] = new Obj[10];

Obj a = new Obj("a");
t[0] = a;

a = new Obj("b");
t[1] = a;
```

Why in java, when i access t[0] , it returns me "a", rather than "b"?
Is this because of the GC? and can i believe it is safe to do such an operation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's exactly what's happening.

```
Obj t[] = new Obj[10];  // 1

Obj a = new Obj("a");   // 2
t[0] = a;

a = new Obj("b");       // 3
t[1] = a;               // 4
```

1. You create an array that can hold 10 references to instances of `Obj`.  Call this `obj01`.  You assign it to `t`.  Note that the variable `t` and the actual object `obj01` have a pretty casual relationship.
2. You create an instance of `Obj`, call this `obj02`.  You assign a reference to this object to the variable `a`.  Note that the variable `a` and the actual object `obj02` have a pretty casual relationship.

   You also put this reference into `t[0]`.  You have one object known in two places.  The object `obj02` (with a value of `"a"`) is known as `a` and known also as `t[0]`.
3. You create an instance of `Obj`, call this `obj03`.  You assign a reference to this new object to the old variable `a`.  Note that the variable `a` and the actual object `obj03` have a pretty casual relationship.   `a` used to reference `obj02`, but it doesn't reference that anymore.

   So, `obj01` (an array) is referenced by `t`; `obj02` (and instance of `Obj`) is known as `t[0]`; `obj03` (an instance of `Obj`) is known as `a`.
4. You put the reference that's in `a` into `t[1]`.  So, `t[1]` gets a reference to `obj03`.

At this point all the objects are referenced by variables which are in scope.  Since all objects have references, they can't be garbage collected.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is, Java doesn't have pointers.

When you assign one object variable to another, it changes what that variable points to but not any other references you might have.

So:

```
Object a = new Object("a");
Object b = new Object("b");

a = b;
b = new Object("c");

// At this point, a = "b"
// and b = "c"
```

As you can see, although you first set a = b, when you then set b to be a new Object, a still retains the reference to the old object.

Comment: Which is exactly what one would expect and not a “problem”, actually. :)

Comment: Sorry, should have made it clearer that this is expected behaviour. Design feature of Java rather than a problem as such.

Answer (score 2):

The value in the array is just a reference. It's just like doing this:

```
Obj a = new Obj("a"); 
Obj t0 = a;
a = new Obj("b");
```

At the end, the `t0` variable has the value it was given on line 2 - that is, a reference to the first `Obj` that's created on line 1. Changing the value of the `a` variable doesn't change the value of t0.

Once you understand the above, just think of an array as a collection of variables, e.g.

```
Obj[] t = new Obj[10];
```

is *roughly* like declaring:

```
Obj t0, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9;
```

(There are plenty of differences, but in the context of this question they're similar.)

Answer (score 1):

When you do t[0] = a; you assign the address of object you created by new Object("a") in the array, whatever you re-use the a variable won't change the value contained in the array.

Answer (score 0):

> *Why in java, when I access t[0] , it returns me "a", rather than "b"?*

Because you told him to hold a reference to the object with "a".

Java don't manipulate directly the objects. Instead I uses has object references. But this reference hold the **value** of the reference ( not the reference  ) So when you assign to  t[0] the value of a, they both reference the same object.

Let's see if this pic explains it better:

[alt text http://img520.imageshack.us/img520/8857/referencesq4.png](http://img520.imageshack.us/img520/8857/referencesq4.png)

First, a and t[0] reference the same object.

Later a drop that reference but t[0] no.

At the end a and t[1](http://img520.imageshack.us/img520/8857/referencesq4.png) reference the same object and t[0] remains unchanged.

> *Is this because of the GC?*

No

> *and can i believe it is safe to do such an operation*

Yes